# Meaning of the expression "beating at an open door"

Tags: meaning

Please, can anyone help me in explaining the English expression "beating at an open door"?

I tried to look on the internet and dictionary to see if I could find an entry that explains it. But I did not find any. But the expression is common everywhere. From how it is used, I guess it means "knocking at an open door", but I cannot be sure. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I can't say I've ever heard the expression but I'd guess it's refering to a pointless exercise. You beat/knock on a door to get someone to open it. If it's already open there's no point in knocking...

Comment: Wiktionary has [kick at an open door](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kick_at_an_open_door#English). "Knocking" also seems popular.

Comment: _Beating_ implies knocking very violently/urgently.

Comment: Some metaphors are opaque, but this one is open-and-shut.

Comment: I have never heard that as an expression, though it’s clear what it means. It sounds like something from another culture, translated.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the conceptual metaphor

'closed door = barrier to proceeding; open door = free opportunity to proceed (with a course of action)'.

We speak of an open-door policy (no qualifications necessary to participate).

The metaphor is used in the Bible:

> - When I came to the city of Troas to preach the Good News of Christ, the Lord opened a door of opportunity for me. [[NLT;
>   BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/2_corinthians/2-12.htm)]

There is the optimistic proverb:

> - When one door shuts, another door opens.

Jesus [[Rev 3:20; NIV; BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/revelation/3-20.htm)] speaks of the need to respond to his invitation:

> - Here I am! I stand at the door and knock. If anyone hears my voice and opens the door, I will come in and eat with that person, and they
>   with me.

'Beating' or 'Knocking' 'at an open door' is an extension, meaning trying to produce an opportunity when there is clearly already no impediment.

> - [It's stupid to] spend time beating at an open door where you already
>   have the general public accepting the principle [[Meetings, agendas, and minutes - Gloucester City Council; 2008](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22beating+at+an+open+door%22&sca_esv=0bd871f8ecc8a9a6&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=O1rPZbTiNafPhbIPr7KcsAw&ved=0ahUKEwj06_CU86-EAxWnZ0EAHS8ZB8YQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%22beating+at+an+open+door%22&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiGSJiZWF0aW5nIGF0IGFuIG9wZW4gZG9vciIyCBAAGIAEGKIEMggQABiABBiiBDIIEAAYgAQYogRIxiNQtghYqyBwAXgBkAEAmAFVoAHZAaoBATO4AQPIAQD4AQHCAgoQABhHGNYEGLADwgIKEAAYFhgeGA8YCsICCxAAGIAEGIoFGIYDiAYBkAYI&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)]

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on Kate Bunting's comment, "beating at a door" suggests the person is hitting it very hard and saying "Let me in!  Let me in!"

If the door is wide open, the person who is beating at it is a fool.